# For loop - doesn't do last loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have this for loop. TicketList starts with 109 tickets.  nColumns = 100.  I calculate the number of rows I will need depending on the number of tickets.  So in this case I need 2 rows.  Row one will be full and row two will only have 9 entries.  I have the loop below.  It only runs one time for the NumOfRows and fills the first 100 and never loops.

What am I missing?

```
for (int j = 0; j < NumOfRows; j++)
  {
       for (int i = 0; i < nColumns; i++)
       {
           if (TicketList.Count() > 0)
           {
               t = rand.Next(0, TicketList.Count() - 1);
               numbers[i, j] = TicketList[t];
               TicketList.Remove(TicketList[t]);
           }
       }                
   }
```

Comment: How about stepping through with a debugger? Or adding some `Trace` statements to see what it is doing?

Comment: To be clear, your outer loop is executing only **once?**

Comment: Show value of `NumOfRows`. Side note: it may be better to shuffle first and than fill rows...

Comment: Did you mix `i` and `j` up in your multidimensional array?  Usually the first index is used to determine the row and the 2nd index is used to determine the column.  Maybe you're expecting the area to be populated the opposite way?

Comment: You know that the second parameter of the `rand.Next` call is exclusive, not inclusive, of the number range you want. You probably should code it as `t = rand.Next(0, TicketList.Count());`. Doesn't solve your problem, but might prevent a logic error.

Comment: Consider using `TicketList.Any()` instead of `TicketList.Count() > 0`

Comment: @RobertHarvey - yes that is exactly correct...the outer loop is only executing one.  Uwe Keim - I did step through with the debugger, I found that the outer loop is only executing once even though I expect it to run twice.  Thanks for all the pointers, I have only been using C# for a few months and find it difficult to find ALL the different ways to accomplish something.

Comment: @Enigmativity - when I used count at one point I got an index out of range error when the process got to the last entry in the ticket list.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your code to use a more LINQ-like, functional approach. If might make the logic easier. Something like this:

```
TicketList
    .OrderBy(x => rand.Next())
    .Select((ticket, n) => new
    {
        ticket,
        j = n / NumOfRows,
        i = n % NumOfRows
    })
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x =>
    {
        numbers[x.i, x.j] = x.ticket;
    });
```

You may need to flip around `x.i` & `x.j` or use `nColumns` instead of `NumOfRows` - I wasn't sure what your logic was looking for - but this code might work better.

Comment: +1. For code that clearly separates steps. Note that `Aggregate()` instead of `ToList.ForEach` sequence would work as well and not require extra copy to list.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - `Aggregate` won't allow assignment statements though. You'd still need some sort of loop to allow the assignment.

Comment: Why? `.Aggregate(0, (_, x) => numbers[x.i, x.j] = x.ticket);`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I stand corrected. I just tested this behaviour and you're right. That works fine too.

Comment: except I don't know anything about LINQ and this is just a little project I am putting together to help out for a fundraiser.  I just want to understand why my outer loop only executes once.  Thanks for the info and hopefully I will have some time in the future to look into it more.

Answer (score 1):

Other than a few poor choices, your loops appear to be fine. I would venture that `NumOfRows` is not being calculated correctly.

The expression `NumOfRows = (TotalTickets + (Columns - 1)) / Columns;` should calculate the correct number of rows.

Also, you should use the property version of `Count` rather than the Linq extension method and use `IList<T>.RemoveAt()` or `List<T>.RemoveAt` rather than `Remove(TicketList[T])`.

Using `Remove()` requires that the list be enumerated to locate the element to remove, which may not be the same index that you are targeting. Not to mention that you will scan 50% (on average) of the list for each Remove call, when you already know the correct index to remove.

The functional approach listed earlier seems like overkill.

I've attempted to replicate your issue, assuming certain facts about the various variables in use. The loop repeats the expected number of times.

```
    static void TestMe ()
    {
        List<object> TicketList = new List<object>();

        for (int index = 0; index < 109; index++)
            TicketList.Add(new object());

        var rand = new Random();
        int nColumns = 100;
        int NumOfRows = (TicketList.Count + (nColumns - 1)) / nColumns;
        object[,] numbers;
        int t;

        numbers = new object[nColumns, NumOfRows];

        for (int j = 0; j < NumOfRows; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OuterLoop");
            for (int i = 0; i < nColumns; i++)
            {
                if (TicketList.Count > 0)
                {
                    t = rand.Next(0, TicketList.Count - 1);
                    numbers[i, j] = TicketList[t];
                    TicketList.RemoveAt(t);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem that you are seeing must be the result of something that you have not included in your sample.

Comment: @Enigmativity - not just overkill, also less efficient.

Comment: In this case I suspect it be more efficient than the OP's code. It's certainly easier to read and debug.

Comment: yes that is the formula I am using to calculate the number of rows...it comes back as 2 in my example just like I would expect.